# Can a bootable USB overwrite my default operating system?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I want to try out a few other operating systems than Windows so I found an interesting one: [Deepin Linux](https://www.deepin.org/en/download/). I downloaded the bootmaker and the ISO and was ready to flash it but then I remembered that it can override my default operating system. So I was not sure if it does so. If someone knows or has advice for me then please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Of course no, you can enable or disable boot from bootable USB from the BIOS settings. After you try it and unplug the USB, it will boot your installed operating system.

Comment: So there is no risk at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few scenarios in which your current system may be damaged:

1. When you write the image to your disk instead of to a USB drive. Some tools may not let you choose a fixed disk, but in general overwriting your OS this way is possible. Mistakes happen.
2. When you play with the other OS, you cast commands and/or click mindlessly and you don't know what you're doing. Mishaps are possible especially when you act as superuser (in Linux: with `sudo` or while being logged in as root) but also when you act a a regular, limited user. E.g. the other OS may provide means for a regular user to mount and alter the filesystem where your Windows is located.
3. When the other OS is buggy or malicious; or when you run a buggy or malicious program in it.

Aside from this it's rather safe. You can try the other OS and programs it provides via its official channels (repositories). Unless you actively try to tamper with the disk holding your Windows, it should be fine.

A ultimate precaution is to physically disconnect the disk with Windows; or to try the other OS via a virtual machine. IMO both methods are overkill.